# TeX4ht: conflict between hyperref and optional arguments of proof

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm}]
  This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `make4ht`, one gets

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   11   Extra \else.
```

There is no error if `hyperref` package is not included. It is also worth to mention that, this issue also appears if we replace `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm}]` by `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\hyperref[thm]{some theorem}]`.

I wonder the reason and a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by removing of some supplemental code for Hyperref in TeX4ht. This was done because of [clashes with BibLaTeX](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?534). As I found also other issues caused by this change, I've reintroduced the original code back to TeX4ht sources. In the meantime, you can use local copy of the `hyperref-hooks.4ht` file:

```
% hyperref-hooks.4ht (2021-12-08-12:41), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-12-08-12:41}

% we don't have any code here for now
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\@ifpackageloaded{nameref}{}
{%
   \let\sv:label\label
   \RequirePackage{nameref}%
   \let\label\sv:label
   %\input nameref.4ht
}}
```

Your example now compiles without errors:

[image]